# print list without using for loop

Tags: python, list

I wish to print elements within a list without using for loop

Example,

```
a = ["I","have","something","to","buy"]
```

Code:

```
from itertools import combinations
aa = list(combinations(a,4))
print("element_{}".format(*aa))
```

2nd code:

```
def word(aa):
    print(aa)
    for x in aa:
        return x

aa = list(combinations(a, len(a)-1))

for wordd in aa:
    aaa.append("element_{}".format(word(list(wordd))))

print(aaa)
```

I tried to use Splat or splatting such as "*" but its not working. I still not master splat.

Expected output:

```
[['element_I', 'element_have', 'element_something', 'element_to'], ['element_I', 'element_have', 'element_something', 'element_buy'], ['element_I', 'element_have', 'element_to', 'element_buy'], ['element_I', 'element_something', 'element_to', 'element_buy'], ['element_have', 'element_something', 'element_to', 'element_buy']]
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use a loop?

Comment: I would like to try something else instead of for loop. I even tried to create another function but its not working. Hold on. I update my latest codes

Comment: The only way to do this without a loop is recursion. It's a horrible idea. (Well, it kind of depends on your definition of a "loop", but you get the point.)

Comment: Well, there's probably a way to do it using `map`, which is *technically* not a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension :

```
from itertools import combinations
aa = list(combinations(a,4))
print([['element_{}'.format(x) for x in e] for e in aa])
```

Output :

```
[['element_I', 'element_have', 'element_something', 'element_to'], ['element_I', 'element_have', 'element_something', 'element_buy'], ['element_I', 'element_have', 'element_to', 'element_buy'], ['element_I', 'element_something', 'element_to', 'element_buy'], ['element_have', 'element_something', 'element_to', 'element_buy']]
```

Using map :

```
from itertools import combinations
aa = list(combinations(a,4))
print(map(lambda x : map(lambda y : 'element_{}'.format(y), x), aa))
```

Comment: Isn't it still using a `for` loop?

Comment: Edited using map, don't know if author considers comprehension list as for loop